# Service With Business Logic To Coordinate Multiple Repositories

Tags: c#, service, dependencies, repository

Hello fellow engineering community,
My team is working on refactoring some code that is currently in a pretty poor state, i.e. database calls all over the code base, like so:

```
public class MyController{
    public void SomeRoute(int id){
        ClassA a = ClassA.Read(id); // Static method that accesses db
        ...
    }
}
```

We are attempting to remove these direct database references for many reasons, not the least of which is it's pretty much impossible to get any test harnesses in place (our project has almost no unit testing at this point).

To that end, I've been creating a number of repositories, one per database table (using the Dapper micro-ORM if that is important). As an example, we have this complicated class structure (just an example, pay no attention to the names or types as they're not important):

```
public class ClassA {
    private List<ClassB> classBList;
    private List<ClassC> classCList;
    private List<ClassD> classDList;
}

public class ClassD {
    private List<ClassE> classEList;
    private List<ClassF> classFList;
    private List<ClassG> classGList;
}
```

At this point, each of those classes (A-G) has its own database table. I've been creating a repository per class, i.e. ClassARepository : IClassARepository, etc.

Now, my controller (or really any class that deals with ClassA) initially had all of these repos injected into it:

```
public class MyController {
    public MyController (IClassARepository repoA, IClassBRepository repoB, ...) {
    }
}
```

I'm sure you're thinking, as I did, that that many constructor args is a code smell, and that my controller is not the place to implement the business logic for persisting all this data. So, I refactored.

There's quite a bit of business logic that goes into persisting ClassA to the database. First, it needs to write itself. Then, it needs to write the lists of ClassB, ClassC, and ClassD. Next, ClassD needs to write its children, Classes E-G. Finally, it needs to delete any items that exist in the database but do not exist in ClassA in memory, i.e. an item from the ClassB list was removed or an item from the ClassF list was removed.

My service initially looked like this:

```
public class ClassAService : IClassAService {
    public ClassAService (ClassARepository repoA, ClassBRepository repoB, ...) {
    }
}
```

But as you can see, I've still got the same number of dependencies, I've just moved them to a different class. Granted, I can now inject only a single dependency into my controller: `public MyController (IClassAService service)`.

My next thought (and where I'm currently 'stuck'), is that ClassD should be responsible for writing its own children, so I created a service for that as well. My ClassAService then becomes:

```
public class ClassAService : IClassAService {
    public ClassAService (ClassARepository repoA, ClassBRepository repoB, ClassCRepository repoC, ClassDService serviceD) {
    }

    // Write ClassA along with all its children if writeChildren is true
    // and remove (prune) any children that aren't in the lists
    public ClassA Write(ClassA classA, bool writeChildren, bool pruneChildren, string username) {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) {
            // Business logic for coordinating all the different updates/deletes, i.e.
            repoA.Write(classA, username);
            repoB.Write(classA.ClassBList, username);
            repoC.Write(classA.ClassCList, username);
            serviceD.Write(classA.ClassDList, writeChildren, pruneChildren, username);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Something still feels wrong about this, but I'm not sure what. What if, for example, ClassA had 5 lists of children instead of 3? Or 15?

I'm looking to the community for your own experiences with this type of issue, and would like to hear your thoughts on this approach.

Thank you for reading, and I look forward to your responses!

Comment: This question was meant for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, not stackoverflow. Is it possible to move?

Comment: not code review instead? also, i think op need to use a more powerful ORM to be able writing multiple rows in a single transaction (sometimes its a necessity to have it).

Comment: Code review may be better. I didn't realize that existed. I'm not sure how to move it though. Thing about a more powerful ORM (i.e. EF) is you've got a performance tradeoff. I don't mind doing a little extra work with transactions to coordinate all of this.

Comment: In its current form it will be closed on code review. Make sure to read the help center to make your question on-topic.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the review. I'll read through the help center and modify the question as needed. Thanks!